# How can I be alerted if a Windows Server 2003 machine's hard drive is approaching full?

Tags: windows-server-2003, monitoring, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

I need to get an email alert when a Windows Server 2003 server's hard drive approaches a certain fill level. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [102745](https://serverfault.com/questions/102745/setting-low-disk-space-alerts-on-windows-server-2008) ?

Comment: Sorry, that does not work for us. We still have to use win 2003.

Comment: ...but the Powershell hint in the same thread should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your performance monitoring to alert you. Please refer the following URL.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299921

If you want more sophisticated answer, you can try AppFirst. They support Perf counters and you can easily configure them to send you an alert and much more.

HTH