# Set Low Disk Space email alerts for windows 10

Tags: windows, email, monitoring, windows-10

I want to set email alerts for my disks, so that if there would be 30GB free space then I will get an email alert.

I found some solutions for windows 2008 but they didn't work for me in Windows 10.
Maybe I did something wrong, or the solution for windows 10 is different.

I tried to use Task Scheduler but it didn't work.
Here is the guide link I used (Mark Pettibone comment): [Setting Low Disk Space Alerts on Windows Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/102745/setting-low-disk-space-alerts-on-windows-server-2008)

Could you help me make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't share what the solution you attempted to use is, we can't help you make it work.

Comment: @Reaces Edited my question with the attempt I tried to do