# Setting Low Disk Space Alerts on Windows Server 2008 for specific partition

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, alerts

Based on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/102745/setting-low-disk-space-alerts-on-windows-server-2008), I need a similair solution for myself (I used Mark Pettibone's answer), however I want to limit it to only specific partitions. I imagine I have to use something different for the source instead of srv, but I have no idea what I need to pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start off with that process and then run a powershell script to warn you when the particular partition has a freespace below a certain level.  Below the code works on Server 2008 RTM (I don't think I have updated the powershell on the box I tested on).

```
GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | Select-Object deviceid, name, freespace
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me instead of needlessly downvoting me.